# Rails : For every x items, put a new html tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have an object named sector.

```
  <div class="col-md-6 md-margin-bottom-40">
    <ul class="list-unstyled categories">
      <% @sectors_name.each do |sector| %>
        <li><%= link_to sector.name, sector_path(sector) %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I would like to have a new column for every 6 `<li></li>`

With my code I just have a list with an infinite scroll. The best would be something like this

```
  <div class="col-md-6 md-margin-bottom-40">
      <% @sectors_name.each do |sector| %>
       <ul class="list-unstyled categories">
        <li><%= link_to sector.name, sector_path(sector) %></li>
      </ul>
     <% end %>
  </div>
```

And when 6 items are displayed, the loop start again and generates a new `<ul>`

Do you have an idea of what I should do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `in_groups_of(n)`:

```
<% @sectors_name.in_groups_of(6) do |sectors| %>
  <% sectors.each do |sector| %>
     <ul class="list-unstyled categories">
      <li><%= link_to sector.name, sector_path(sector) %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`in_group_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) method. Your code will look like:

```
<% @sectors_name.in_groups_of(6) do |sectors| %>
  <ul class="list-unstyled categories">
    <% sectors.each do |sector| %>
      <li><%= link_to sector.name, sector_path(sector) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
 <% end %>
```